# Google Analytics Data API - HTML to Apps Script: gapi is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

I am trying to execute a Report with the Google Analytics Data API. I built the request using [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport?apix_params=%7B%22property%22%3A%22properties%2F295880176%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22metrics%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22sessions%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22conversions%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22totalRevenue%22%7D%5D%2C%22dimensions%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22week%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22year%22%7D%5D%2C%22dateRanges%22%3A%5B%7B%22startDate%22%3A%222021-01-01%22%2C%22endDate%22%3A%22today%22%7D%5D%7D%7D) and I get this script. The script works well if I execute it directly with the "Try this method" option in the documentation:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for analyticsdata.properties.runReport
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/code-samples#javascript
   */

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1beta")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.analyticsdata.properties.runReport({
      "property": "properties/295880876",
      "resource": {
        "metrics": [
          {
            "name": "sessions"
          },
          {
            "name": "conversions"
          },
          {
            "name": "totalRevenue"
          }
        ],
        "dimensions": [
          {
            "name": "week"
          },
          {
            "name": "year"
          }
        ],
        "dateRanges": [
          {
            "startDate": "2021-01-01",
            "endDate": "today"
          }
        ]
      }
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

Now I want to run this Script in Apps Script and import the Data to a spreadsheet. However as this is a HTML, if I want to run it as a JS and delete the script tags and content I receive "gapi is not defined".

It is clear that I still have to load https://apis.google.com/js/api.js somehow, but how?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to use "Method: properties.runReport" with Google Apps Script.

When I saw your showing script, it seems that it is used for Javascript. In this case, Javascript is different from Google Apps Script. I think that this might be the reason for your issue.

In order to achieve your goal, in the current stage, Advanced Google services can be used. So, in this answer, I would like to propose using AnalyticsData with the Advanced Google services of Google Apps Script.

The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, [please enable "AnalyticsData" at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set your property ID to `###` of `const property = "properties/###";`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Retrieve values from Google Analytics Data API (GA4)
  const property = "properties/###"; // Please set your property ID.
  const resource = {
    "metrics": [
      {
        "name": "sessions"
      },
      {
        "name": "conversions"
      },
      {
        "name": "totalRevenue"
      }
    ],
    "dimensions": [
      {
        "name": "week"
      },
      {
        "name": "year"
      }
    ],
    "dateRanges": [
      {
        "startDate": "2021-01-01",
        "endDate": "today"
      }
    ]
  };
  const obj = AnalyticsData.Properties.runReport(resource, property);

  // Put values to Spreadsheet.
  const header = [...obj.dimensionHeaders.map(({ name }) => name), ...obj.metricHeaders.map(({ name }) => name)];
  const values = [header, ...obj.rows.map(({ dimensionValues, metricValues }) => [...dimensionValues.map(({ value }) => value), ...metricValues.map(({ value }) => value)])];

  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName)
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When you run this script, the values are retrieved from "properties.runReport", and the retrieved values are put into the Spreadsheet.

#### Note:

- I cannot know the final result you expect from `Now I want to run this Script in Apps Script and import the Data to a spreadsheet.`. So, in the above sample script, the retrieved values are put to "Sheet1" as the header of `week,year,sessions,conversions,totalRevenue`. If you want to change this, please modify this for your actual situation.

#### Reference:

- [Method: properties.runReport](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport)